# Android AsyncTask Issue with Post Request

Tags: php, android, json, android-asynctask, progressdialog

i'm trying to retrieve JSONs from my own PHP Server.
The server side part of my work is fine, infact it returns me a JSON file that i import in my Android application quite easily.
However, have a look to my code :

**My onCreate method**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loans_list);
    setTitle("Catalogo Libri");
    bookList = new ArrayList<>();
    new LoadAllBooks().execute();
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

**My AsyncTask class**

```
class LoadAllBooks extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ArrayList<String> titoli = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> autori = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Bitmap> immagini = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoansList.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading books. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        postRequest("0");
        //
        for (Map m : bookList) {
            titoli.add((String) m.get("Title"));
            autori.add((String) m.get("Author"));
            byte[] data = Base64.decode((String) m.get("Cover"), Base64.DEFAULT);
            immagini.add(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length));

        }
        authors = autori.toArray(new String[autori.size()]);
        names = titoli.toArray(new String[titoli.size()]);
        images = immagini.toArray(new Bitmap[immagini.size()]);

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListView l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.books);
                CustomAdapter ad = new CustomAdapter();
                l.setAdapter(ad);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

**My Custom Adapter Class**

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
        ImageView im = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cover);
        TextView t1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView t2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.author);
        im.setImageBitmap(images[i]);
        t1.setText(names[i]);
        t2.setText(authors[i]);

        return view;
    }
}



**My PostRequest method :** 

    public void postRequest(final String user_id) {
    final String[] a = new String[1];
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoansList.this);
    String url = getBooksPhp;
    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    a[0] = response;
                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(a[0]);
                        books = json.getJSONArray("books");
                        try {
                            // looping through All Products
                            for (int i = 0; i < books.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = books.getJSONObject(i);
                                // creating new HashMap
                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                                map.put("Title", c.getString("Titolo"));
                                map.put("Author", c.getString("Autore")); 
                                map.put("Cover", c.getString("Copertina"));

                                System.out.println("CIAO " + c.getString("Autore"));

                                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                                bookList.add(map);
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println("OH NO");
        }
    }) {
        //adding parameters to the request
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("user_id", user_id);
            return params;
        }
    };
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

**My PostRequest method :**

```
    public void postRequest(String user_id) {
    final String[] a = new String[1];
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoansList.this);
    String url = getBooksPhp;
    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    a[0] = response;
                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(a[0]);
                        books = json.getJSONArray("books");
                        try {
                            // looping through All Products
                            for (int i = 0; i < books.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = books.getJSONObject(i);
                                // creating new HashMap
                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                                map.put("Title", c.getString("Titolo"));
                                map.put("Author", c.getString("Autore")); 
                                map.put("Cover", c.getString("Copertina"));

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                                bookList.add(map);
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println("OH NO");
        }
    }) {
        //adding parameters to the request
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("user_id", user_id);
            return params;
        }
    };
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Now, the problem is that the ProgressDialog is not showing.
It first create the view and then it finishes my request.
Now, i know that AsyncTask is not blocking, but what i'm trying to do is something like :

when i start the activity a progressdialog appears until the asynctask finishes to grab data -> i get the json -> i parse it ->  i build my array of content (cover images, titles and authors) -> i pass the data to my CustomAdapter that makes the ListView for me.

So, how can i do to "sync" threads and control my program flow as i would like?

Thank you !

Comment: `public void postRequest(final String user_id)` Why did you post that code twice? Please edit your post.

Comment: You should not call postRequest() in the doInBackground of an Asynctask. You can call it directly. No need for an asynctask.

Comment: It makes no sense to use runOnUiThread() in onPostExecute().

Comment: I followed up this tutorial with a little bit of changes : https://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql.

So i'm opended to advices.
How can i correct my code ?

Comment: What you call 'little bit of changes' ;-) Exchanging that synchronous  json parser call by an asynchrous Volley call.

Comment: Yes, because it uses Get requests instead of post and a different adapter.

Comment: What yes ??????? The json parser can do a GET too. But that is not the point.

Comment: Now i will revise my code, i think i've done a mess.

Comment: with what context are you creating your ProgressDialog ?

Comment: Ok, guys, now i solved the problem.
Thank you !